# Ajax sourced data in JSON format - Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, datatables

I'm trying to load json data (retrieved from a Web API ajax call) to a jQuery DataTables, but I am getting the following error:

> Unhandled exception at line 38, column 314 in
>   https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
>
> 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'length'
>   of undefined or null reference

This is my jQuery call:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#stat').DataTable({
        "responsive": true,
        "paging": false,
        "ordering": false,
        "info": false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            'url': 'http://localhost:61178/api/financeStats'
        }
    });
});
```

and this is my JSON data retrieved from the Web API call:

```
[
    {
        "Description": "Total Sas debt at yesterday",
        "TotAgents": 788,
        "TotAmount": 1767595.5854
    },
    {
        "Description": "Total CL Sas with Rid worked yesterday",
        "TotAgents": 413,
        "TotAmount": 3026100
    },
    {
        "Description": "Total CL Sas with No Rid worked yesterday",
        "TotAgents": 164,
        "TotAmount": 1252650
    },
    {
        "Description": "Total Debt Sas with Rid to be cleared today",
        "TotAgents": 35,
        "TotAmount": 59448.7522
    },
    {
        "Description": "Debt Sas with No Rid to be cleared today",
        "TotAgents": 157,
        "TotAmount": 478285.384
    },
    {
        "Description": "Today Claim opened",
        "TotAgents": 125,
        "TotAmount": 146262.6726
    },
    {
        "Description": "Today Claim still opened",
        "TotAgents": 51,
        "TotAmount": 113485.4991
    },
    {
        "Description": "Today Claim opened & postponed",
        "TotAgents": 18,
        "TotAmount": 27726.748
    },
    {
        "Description": "Today Claim closed by the operators",
        "TotAgents": 8,
        "TotAmount": 4540.1682
    },
    {
        "Description": "Today Claim closed by the system",
        "TotAgents": 47,
        "TotAmount": -4699.3427
    },
    {
        "Description": "Today Claim Locked Sdd",
        "TotAgents": 1,
        "TotAmount": 5209.6
    },
    {
        "Description": "Today Claim Locked No Sdd",
        "TotAgents": 0,
        "TotAmount": 0
    },
    {
        "Description": "Today Claim UnLocked proposal",
        "TotAgents": 0,
        "TotAmount": 0
    },
    {
        "Description": "Overall Claim Locked Sdd",
        "TotAgents": 3,
        "TotAmount": 7196.54
    },
    {
        "Description": "Overall Claim Locked No Sdd",
        "TotAgents": 2,
        "TotAmount": 1714.1
    },
    {
        "Description": "Overall Claim Unlocked proposal",
        "TotAgents": 3,
        "TotAmount": -155.33
    },
    {
        "Description": "Overall Workout",
        "TotAgents": 541,
        "TotAmount": 619838.3527
    }
]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### CAUSE

Errors `Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference` (IE) or `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` (other browsers) with jQuery DataTables usually means that the plugin cannot access the data in response from Ajax request.

There are several issues with your code

- You have enabled server-side processing mode with `serverSide: true` but your data is formatted for client-side processing mode instead. Remove `serverSide: true` to use client-side processing mode.
- Your data is array of objects. In this case you need to use [`columns`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns) option to define property name in the data set for each column using [`data`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data) option.
- You need to use `dataSrc: ""` to match your JSON data format, see [`dataSrc`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) for more information.

#### SOLUTION

Use the code below:

```js
$('#stat').DataTable({
    "responsive": true,
    "paging": false,
    "ordering": false,
    "info": false,
    "searching": false,
    "ajax": {
        "url": "http://localhost:61178/api/financeStats",
        "dataSrc": ""
    },
    "columns": [
        { "data": "Description" },
        { "data": "TotAgents" },
        { "data": "TotAmount" }
    ]
});
```

#### DEMO

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xb60xptb/1/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Got "Object doesn't support property or method 'DataTable'" error

Comment: @Vkl125, most likely you forgot to include DataTable v1.10 JS files, or using older DataTable libary v.1.9.